# How to display the one band layer in pseudocolor using ERDAS Imagine?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, er-mapper

I am a new user in ERDAS imagine and i found it hard to turn the single band raster data  from grey color to pseudocolor using ERDAS imagine.

This process could be easier to be performed using ER Mapper but i can not found that there are existing color scheme available in ERDAS for better visualization purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loading the image itself, in the File window you should find another Tab that allows you to open the Image in Pseudo color form.

Once done, you can view the histogram distribution and alter the color of the pixel values of your choice.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Does it mean i have to assign different color to each pixel value one by one manually instead of applying a pseudocolor scheme to transform the grey color image to pseudocolor image?

Comment: The advantage with Pseudo color composite is that it can help you highlight a certain pixel of interest. For example, if a target has a pixel value between 150-175, changing the color of only this range will help you identify the locations where this target is present.